# What percentage of the Jewish population were Karaites at the peak of the Karaite movement?

Tags: history, non-rabbinic-judaism

I've been researching about the Karaite movement, but I've struggled to find good sources regarding their numbers. [This website](https://www.ynetnews.com/travel/article/ByyPbShSd) claims that some sources estimate that Karaites comprised as much as 40% of the Jewish population at their peak. That seems like an unusually large number, and also they don't seem to have stated what sources they're getting this from. Therefore, I'd like to ask if any previous estimates have been made that are reliable.

Comment: The figure 40% comes from Salo Wittmayer Baron.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Thank you for sharing that. He seems like a reputable source, but not necessarily too recent. I wonder if the more contemporary scholars agree with this estimate, taking into account the most cutting-edge data and information that we have.